# Binding to a property within an instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I'm working on a project that is getting data from a backend, ie, the data is constantly changing dynamically, and the frontend shouldn't have to care.
I need to expose this data to wpf such that someone can bind things to the data in wpf via expression blend. Readonly is fine. 
In short, how do I do databinding to the property Foostring in a instance of a class "foo" of type "Foo" if my flow of control is roughly the following:

```cs
 public partial class Window1 : window
 {
      public Window1()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
           Foo foo = new foo;
      }
   // my text box is defined in the xaml of this window.

 }

public ref class Foo
{
     Foo()
    {
         FooProperty = "work,dammit";
    }
    private string _foostring="";
    public string FooProperty
    {
       get {return _foostring;}
        set {foostring=value;} 

    }
}
```

I can get things to work if in the constructor of the Foo class I set binding on the text box, and if I inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged and raise an event on the setting of FooProperty.
However, this does not expose this variable to expression blend--it's not really setting a datasource. I've tried to set the binding in xaml and it compiles but doesn't update.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused. You want to do simple binding from xaml to property? That should be no problem: implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Foo` class, set instance of this class as `DataContext` for this window and just bind to this property. Remember that you need to raise `PropertyChanged` event each and every time property has changed. I don't see any problem with it. I don't know what do you mean when saying: "in the constructor of the Foo class I set binding on the text box" - that's definitely not, what you should do.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I needed.

Comment: What I needed to do was instantiate the object in xaml and then reference it in c++. I was instantiating it in c++ and referencing it in xaml, and when I created a static resource, xaml was creating its own instance and not getting any of my updates. For posterity's sake, the final xaml ended up as the detailed solution above.

Comment: If you add your solution as an answer, I'll select it as the chosen solution!

Comment: If Pako is not going to post an answer you should do so yourself, also accept it as soon as you can please.

Answer (score 1):

**[Answer by Rokujolady]**
For posterity, I've posted the solution:
I was instancing the object foo from c# when I should have been instancing from xaml, because xaml was creating its own instance which was not being updated because I was updating the c# instantiated instance. Apparently you can't reference an object created in c# from xaml, but you can reference one created in xaml from c#. The code ended up like this:
XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
<local:Foo x:Name "foo" x:Key="FooDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
...
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:name="blah">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource FooDataSource}}">
<TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding FooProperty, Mode=Default}"></TextBlock></Grid>
```

C# Code looked like this:

```cs
public partial class Window1:window
{
     Foo myFooVariable = null;
     public Window1()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          myFooVariable = this.Resources["FooDataSource"] as Foo;
          myFooVariable.FooString = "Work, Dammit";
     }
}
```